# connecting to oracle

Tags: visual-studio, oracle

I have a report server project in VS2005, and I added an oracle data source to my project and I did anything like my colleage! both of us did the same settings but I can't connect to the server. I connected to DB in TOAD but in VS2005 I couldn't. What should I check?
I get this error during test connection :
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried **HOST:PORT/MYDB** ServerName section to connect to oracle directly and it worked.

Comment: Excellent! Sometimes we just dig too deep for simple solution! ;P

Answer (score 2):

We had issues connecting to databases using the TNSNAMES.ora in Visual Studio 2010.
The TNSNAMES file was correct, the oracle installation was correct, but the connections could not be selected in the "Add Connection" screen.
It turned out that the TNSNAMES had too many entries for the Data Source name select field in the "Add Connection" screen.
Reducing the entries in the TNSNAMES file resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should do fine with the following link:

[ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified](http://ora-12154.ora-code.com/)

**Cause:**

A connection to a database or other service was requested using a connect identifier, and the connect identifier specified could not be resolved into a connect descriptor using one of the naming methods configured. For example, if the type of connect identifier used was a net service name then the net service name could not be found in a naming method repository, or the repository could not be located or reached.

**Action:**

> - *If you are using local naming (TNSNAMES.ORA file):*

- Make sure that "TNSNAMES" is listed as one of the values of the NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH parameter in the Oracle Net profile (SQLNET.ORA)
- Verify that a TNSNAMES.ORA file exists and is in the proper directory and is accessible.
- Check that the net service name used as the connect identifier exists in the TNSNAMES.ORA file.
- Make sure there are no syntax errors anywhere in the TNSNAMES.ORA file. Look for unmatched parentheses or stray characters. Errors in a TNSNAMES.ORA file may make it unusable.

> *- If you are using directory naming:*

- Verify that "LDAP" is listed as one of the values of the NAMES.DIRETORY_PATH parameter in the Oracle Net profile (SQLNET.ORA).
- Verify that the LDAP directory server is up and that it is accessible.
- Verify that the net service name or database name used as the connect identifier is configured in the directory.
- Verify that the default context being used is correct by specifying a fully qualified net service name or a full LDAP DN as the connect identifier

> *- If you are using easy connect naming:*

- Verify that "EZCONNECT" is listed as one of the values of the NAMES.DIRETORY_PATH parameter in the Oracle Net profile (SQLNET.ORA).
- Make sure the host, port and service name specified are correct.
- Try enclosing the connect identifier in quote marks. See the Oracle Net Services Administrators Guide or the Oracle operating system specific guide for more information on naming.

**EDIT**

[Problem connecting to Oracle database](http://www.devnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.adonet/topic29918.aspx)

[Build a .NET Application on the Oracle Database with Visual Studio 2005 or 2008](http://www.oracle.com/technology/pub/articles/cook_dotnet.html)

[Problems connecting to Oracle 9i database with Oracle 10g Client and Win XP x64](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-2877236.php)

[Connection strings for Oracle](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle)

Comment: I checked them all, I even reinstall my oracle 10g. but still have problem

Comment: What DataProvider are you using, System.Data.OracleClient or Oracle.DataAccess.Client? Is it's the first one, try using Oracle.DataAccess.Client since the provider for Oracle supplied by Microsoft is buggy.

Comment: I know every thing in my TNSNAMES.ora is ok. becouse I can connect in TOAD.

Comment: Is Visual Studio using the same TNSNAMES as Toad? Try using Oracle.DataAccess.Client to connect to Oracle, if you don't already.